# Deriving Nakajima–Zwanzig

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body, time-evolution

I would like help on one step of the derivation of the Nakajima–Zwanzig equations. Specifically given the below equations:
$${\partial_t}\left( \begin{matrix}
   \mathcal{P}  \\
   \mathcal{Q}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\rho =\left( \begin{matrix}
   \mathcal{P}  \\
   \mathcal{Q}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)L\left( \begin{matrix}
   \mathcal{P}  \\
   \mathcal{Q}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\rho +\left( \begin{matrix}
   \mathcal{P}  \\
   \mathcal{Q}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)L\left( \begin{matrix}
   \mathcal{Q}  \\
   \mathcal{P}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\rho,$$

I would like to understand how to formally solve them to get the below equation:
$$\mathcal{Q}\rho ={{e}^{\mathcal{Q}Lt}}Q\rho (t=0)+\int_{0}^{t}dt'{e}^{\mathcal{Q}Lt'}\mathcal{Q}L\mathcal{P}\rho (t-{t}') $$

Many places just say the equations can be formally solved, such as:

1. This SE question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16901/equation-of-motion-for-the-reduced-density-matrix/16960#16960), which gives me the impression that I could check this by substituting in the solution. However I would like to derive the formal solution (i.e., if I was not given the solution, how would one go about deriving it).
2. [This reference](http://www.fmt.if.usp.br/%7Egtlandi/12---microscopic-derivation.pdf) simplifies the problem down to the core constituents, which is a coupled first order set of differential equations. However it then introduces Green functions, which I am not familiar with in the context of solving coupled first order equations.
3. The Wikipedia reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakajima%E2%80%93Zwanzig_equation) includes a bit more information in their note 3 that includes an exponential, but I don't know where that exponential comes from.

Comment: [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#System_of_linear_differential_equations) might help. This has the solution to the formal integration in Landi's notes.

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful!